# akka camel ftp. Exception checking connection status: File operation failed: null Connection is not open. Code: 0

Tags: ftp, apache-camel, akka

My akka camel ftp app worked fine and I didn't touch it for a long time. But since several days ago it stopped to consume files (it works fine locally with the same ftp server). No errors etc. 
Settings:

```
ftp://user@myip.com?delay=600000&filter=%23datFileFilter&initialDelay=1000&password=xxxxxx&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&username=user
```

I switched on trace and found:

```
Exception checking connection status: File operation failed: null Connection is not open. Code: 0
```

,

```
Exception checking connection status: File operation failed: 250 OK. Current directory is /
 Connection reset. Code: 250
```

,

```
User XXXX logged in: true
```

,

```
No files found in directory:
```

which is not true, because SAME code works fine on localhost

Some time ago server crushed and restarted. maybe something left. I rebuilt rpm and restarted.

Comment: Could you post the whole stack trace (is there perhaps a `Caused by: java.net.«SomeException»` in the trace?)

Comment: Hello @raphaëλ. nothing. no errors or exceptions. only debug I sent above. it authenticate and cannot find files. but locally it works fine